# Solr Lucene - Not sure how to index data so documents scored properly

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Here's my goal.  A user has a list of skill+proficiency tuples.

We want to find users based on some skill/experience criteria:

- java, novice
- php, expert

  mysql, advanced

Where the * skills are highly desired and all others are good to have.  Users which meet or exceed (based on experience) would be ranked highest.  But it should also degrade nicely.  If no users have both java and php experience, but they have one of the highly desired skills they should be ranked at the top.  Users with only one of the optional skills may appear at the bottom.

An idea I had is to index a user's skills in fields like this:

```
skill_novice: java
skill_novice: php
skill_advanced: php
skill_expert: php
skill_novice: mysql
skill_advanced: mysql
```

...so that at minimal I can do a logical query to find people who meeting the highly desired skills:

```
(skill_novice:java AND skill_expert:php)
```

but this doesn't degrade nicely (if no matches found) nor does it find the optional skills.  Perhaps instead I can do something like this:

```
skill_novice:java AND
  (skill_novice:php^0.1 OR skill_advanced:php^0.2 OR skill_expert:php^0.3)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could boost the field with the different values at index time:

```
  // mysql expert
  Field mysqlf = new Field("skill", "mysql", 
                                    Field.Store.YES, 
                                    Field.Index.ANALYZED); 
  mysqlf.setBoost(10.0F); 
  // mysql begginer
  mysqlf = new Field("skill", "mysql", 
                                    Field.Store.YES, 
                                    Field.Index.ANALYZED); 
  mysqlf.setBoost(1.0F);
```

You need to enable norms for this to work.

Comment: Thanks. I read that in solr the boost is only per field, not the field value.  So here "skill" is the field and "mysql" is the value. Or is this not true or out of date info?